# Odoo - open a form in editable mode

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I have a tree view in my custom module. When user clicks on an item of tree view it takes user to the form view and user have to click edit button in order to edit the form. I want to open the form view automatically in edit mode. So, user didn't have to click specially on Edit button

Comment: What you have tried that describe here..

Answer (score 1):

Pls try with this in **ir.actions.act_window**:

```
<field name='flags'>{'initial_mode': 'edit'}</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

In form's **ir.actions.act_window** record add:

```
<field name='target'>inline</field>
```

Comment: This will sometimes affects the UI.

Comment: This line just hide the Create/Edit button from the the UI and directly opens th eform in edit only mode.

Comment: I really didn't expect your reply, its been 3 years you ve posted this :). Yes @rahul but is there any way to get the output without getting any damage to the UI? Thanks for your reply